# How to know when to create an interface vs. defining an object directly in the function signature in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, function, interface

What is the standard way of writing Typescript functions? For example, which of the three following is ideal:

```js
// 1
function myFunction (a: string) {}

// 2
function myFunction ({ a }: { a: string }) {}

// 3
interface IMyFunction {
  a: string
}

function myFunction (input: IMyFunction) {}
```

Does the answer change if there are 3 variables, for example?

Are there good reference docs for these types of questions?

Comment: Whether to use an inline type or a type alias (example 2 vs example 3) for your arguments would depend on a lot of factor (complexity of types, if they get reused anywhere, etc). But you should know that example 1 vs example 2 and 3 have different signatures. One takes a string, and the other take an object. Which if those to use depends on how you want to design your API. In general, I would argue that if a function takes an object, it's generally a good idea to defined that object as it's own interface. But for simple cases with minimal reuse, example 2 works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of these are ideal and there are no docs for these types of questions, because it's totally up to you to decide. It's like arguing whether it's necessary to write semicolons at the end of each line in JavaScript: I don't write them, but many people do and that's no problem.

As a general rule, it may be better to use plain arguments, when it is obvious, what their purpose is, like `Math.sqrt` takes a number, and it's obvious, why and what does it do with it. Other examples when arguments work the best are:

```
function getUserById(id: number) { /* ... */ }
getUserById(12523)

function displayMessage(text: string) { /* ... */ }
displayMessage('Hello')
```

Again, no one prohibits you to use objects and interfaces, it's just that in these examples the meaning of the arguments is obvious and there are not a lot of them.

Look at this function:

```
function getUserById(id: number, includeDescription: boolean) {}
```

In this case you may want to use objects instead of plain arguments, because if I write `getUserById(12345, true)`, it's unclear, what this `true` means unless you remember how you wrote this function or look at it's definition. So you could write it like this

```
function getUserById({ 
  id, 
  includeDescription 
}: {
  id: number,
  includeDescription?: boolean
}) {}
```

This is completely fine, unless you use this object type somewhere else. If you do, then you may want to write an interface or a type alias instead, so that you don't have to repeat your code later. Personally, I usually write type aliases, because when in your editor you hover over arguments, declared with interfaces, it shows just the name of the interface, but with type aliases, it shows the entire object definition, so this is quicker

```
type GetUserByIdOptions = {
  id: number
  includeDescription?: boolean
}
function getUserById({ id, includeDescription }: GetUserByIdOptions) {}
```

Also usually if you have many arguments (like more than 3), then you would want to use objects, because it's just easier to remember, what these arguments are like this. Also you won't have to remember their order. But again, it's completely up to you, just write whatever looks nicer to you and whatever you feel like.

Comment: Thank you! This line really helped me understand:

"It's like arguing whether it's necessary to write semicolons at the end of each line in JavaScript"